# PostgreSQL: Index JSONB array that is queried with `@?` operator

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

My table (`table`) has a JSONB field (`data`) that contains a field with an array where I store tags (`tags`).
I query that table with an expression like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->'tags' @? '$[*] ? (@ like_regex ".*(foo|bar).*" flag "i");
```

With such use-case is there a way for me to index the `data->'tags'` array to speed up the query? Or should I rather work on moving the `tags` array out of the JSONB field and into a TEXT[] field and index that?

I've already tried:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl USING GIN ((data->'tags') jsonb_path_ops);
```

but it doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/vkaracic/a62ac917d34eb6e975c4daeefbd316e8

Comment: testing an index on table with only one row is completely meaningless. A `Seq Scan` will always be the best choice for such a tiny table. You need to populate it with a lot more data ("hundreds of thousand") to test the efficiency of the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index you built can be used (if you set enable_seqscan=off, you will see that it does get used), but it is generally not chosen as it is pretty useless for this query.  The only rows it would rule out through the index are the ones that don't have the 'tags' key at all, and even at that is poorly estimated so probably won't be used without drastic measures.

You could try to convert to text[] and the use [parray_gin](https://github.com/theirix/parray_gin), but probably better would be to convert to a child table with text and then use pg_trgm.